# google map with weather information

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, weather, google-weather-api

Consider the requirement to integrate the road direction between two stations, along with the weather information of the starting, middle, and destination stations.

I looked at the Google help, but I didn't find the weather information along with the direction map/

How can weather information be added?

Comment: i want something like this http://www.wunderground.com/roadtrip

Answer (score 1):

Three are some weather APIs on this page

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507441/best-weather-apis

Query your preferred weather API with the points you wish to get the weather for.

Comment: thank to reply dear. i looked that page but that is talking about only weahter api while i want to get the direction map along with the weather information.

Comment: well the google directions api is clearly documented, go to the documentation and start learning.